# How can I pass imagePullSecrets, as it is defined in the default template, to helm via set commands

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

When you run `helm create mychart` it has imagePullSecrets defined like this:

```
spec:
  {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
  imagePullSecrets:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
  {{- end }
```

In default values file it looks like it's passing it a blank array:

```
imagePullSecrets: []
```

I already have a bunch of charts built from this default template that have this setting. Previously I didn't need to use imagePullSecrets so I just left it as is, but now I have some cases where I want to set this at deploy time via the cli.

Helm supports arrays now but this doesn't seem to work:

```
--set "mychart.imagePullSecrets[0].name={reg-creds}"
```

Returns:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets[0].name): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.LocalObjectReference.name: got "array", expected "string"
```

Then I tried passing a string:

`--set "mychart.imagePullSecrets='- name: reg-creds'"`

```
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.imagePullSecrets): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec.imagePullSecrets: got "string", expected "array"
```

These error messages are infuriating. Is it possible to set this value with `--set` so I can avoid refactoring all my charts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`helm install --set` syntax](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) is unique and complex.  One unusual bit of syntax there is that a value `{foo,bar}` in curly braces sets the value to an array.  In your example, then, `--set object.path={value}` sets the value to a single-element array; the error you see is that it needs to be a string instead.

That means a simple workaround here is to remove the curly braces on the right-hand side of `--set`.  There is also a `--set-string` option that forces the value to be interpreted as a string, even if it contains curly braces or commas.

```sh
helm install ... --set "mychart.imagePullSecrets[0].name=reg-creds"
#                       no curly braces around the value ^^^^^^^^^
```

It might be clearer, and have a more standard syntax, to use a YAML file to provide this value instead.

```yaml
# image-pull-secrets.yaml
imagePullSecrets:
  - name: reg-creds
```

You can include this in a per-environment values file, or pass it as a standalone values file.  In either case you'd use the `helm install -f` option to supply the file.  It's fine to have multiple `helm install -f` values files.

```sh
helm install ... -f image-pull-secrets.yaml
```